# Can't burn newly created playlist to CD with iTunes 12.1

Tags: itunes, music, optical-drive, cd-burning

I just want to burn some music for my Mom to a CD-R.  I've done this multiple times. If I check MP3 CD box, I receive message stating all music is not MP3, and it won't allow. If I check other option, Data CD or DVD, it copies but if I insert into CD player, message is, " No Audio."

This can't be this hard.

Any help is appreciated.

I have OS 10.7.5

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you go to View Options and selected Kind, you'll be able to see which of the tracks isn't an MP3. You can then convert it/them to MP3 and replace the originals in your playlist with the new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Does your Mom have an MP3 CD capable player? How many tracks are you trying to burn to the CD?  If you burn it as a standard audio CD, it will hold a little over an hour of music. If you burn it as an MP3 CD, it will burn as many MP3 files as can fit on a 650 MB CD-R. When you say you check other option to burn it as a Data CD, and you insert into a non-MP3 capable CD player, you would get a message that there is nothing to play. Otherwise, the way I would do it is this:  Insert a blank CD-R then drag the MP3 files directly onto the disc using Finder. You wouldn't even need to use iTunes.